# Who is the protagonist in the Hobbit movies?

Tags: pov, protagonist, hero

You might think it is Bilbo (because it's his POV), but doesn't he play a rather minor role in the task to reclaim the mountain?

Isn't Thorin the one who is the causer of effects, who makes decisions, who faces a transformation of character at the end and then kills the enemy?

But on the other hand, don't you end up rooting for Bilbo?

Comment: (sigh) Again, **protagonist ≠ hero**. Hero does the noble heroic stuff and is larger-than-life and has a destiny (and often sacrifices/dies). Protagonist is someone *relatable* who is the eyes and POV for the reader.... This was of course BEFORE every story became a Mary Sue chosen-one wish-fulfillment clone.

Comment: I recall that we had this discussion before and I also recall that I proposed (having learned that from Weiland) that the "protagonist" is the character whose inner arc drives the external plot, not necessarily the POV character which is why I asked (and that's the question you commented on) if there are novels where the POV character is not the protagonist, which there seemingly are. Hence, your theory is either incomplete or I did not understand it yet. But I'm always happy to learn if you are willing to have this discussion.

Comment: Also, I'm curious as to which stories you refer to when you say that modern writing is full of Mary Sue wish-fulfillment clones. Can you name a few? I'm genuinely interested in your picks.

Comment: @Alon "character whose inner arc drives the external plot" - how do you define "drives" and "external plot"? For example, in "All Quiet on the Western Front", Paul Bäumer is the protagonist, but is his inner arc driving WWI events in any way?

Answer (score 3):

Because Bilbo goes through the greatest degree of change, from reluctant adventurer to tricking Gollum into showing him the way out of the goblin caves, to saving the party, twice, to stealing the Arkenstone that led directly to the death of Smaug, he is the protagonist of the story.

Comment: And that's also why Thanos is the protagonist of Avengers: Infinity War.

Comment: @Mindwin, while Thanos under goes a surface transformation, Tony Stark goes from hubris -- The Earth is closed today, Squidward -- to fearful -- I can't risk what  I have to bring everyone back -- to self-sacrificing -- I am Iron man.  Hulk goes through similar arcs as does Captain America and Hawkeye and Blackwidow and all of the Avengers

Comment: I'm not bundling together Endgame with Infinity War. Note I spoke only of the latter. All the heroes are side characters in "Infinity War". The one who goes the whole 17 steps is Thanos.